# In Declarative Pipeline, can I make a parallel stage that runs the same code an arbitrary number of times (on an arbitrary number of nodes)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that does a handful of things, but at the end of the build I would like to run tests on multiple copies of the same build node. These tests will all be identical, and they will all run on fresh clones of the same VM.

Can the parallel block do something to that degree? As far as I can tell, I COULD do something like this:

```
...
stage('Parallel Testing'){
    parallel{
        stage('Run1'){
            agent{
                label "my_test_machines"
            }
            steps{
                run_my_tests()
            }
        }
        stage('Run2'){
            agent{
                label "my_test_machines"
            }
            steps{
                run_my_tests()
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
...
```

But that is obviously pretty ugly and would get awful if I wanted to do more than a few parallel nodes. Is there some way to make parallel{} run on a for loop, or otherwise create an arbitrary number of stages/nodes?

Comment: Have you looked at [`matrix`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix)?

Answer (score 0):

You can program your parallel stages like this:

```
stage('Parallel Testing') {
   steps {
      script {
         def builders = getParallelBuilders()
         parallel builders
      }
   }
}
```

where

```
def getParallelBuilders() {
    def builders = [:].asSynchronized()
    def my_runs = ["Run1", "Run2", "Run3"]

    my_runs.each { stage_name -> 
        def final_name = stage_name
        builders[final_name] = {
            stage (final_name) {
                node("my_test_machines") {
                   run_my_tests()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return builders
}
```