# Can Jenkins pipelines have variable stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

From my experience with Jenkins declarative-syntax pipelines, I'm aware that you can conditionally skip a stage with a `when` clause. E.g.:

```
run_one = true
run_two = false
run_three = true

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('one') {
            when {
                expression { run_one }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'one'
            }
        }
        stage('two') {
            when {
                expression { run_two }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'two'
            }
        }
        stage('three') {
            when {
                expression { run_three }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'three'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...in the above code block, there are three stages, `one`, `two`, and `three`, each of whose execution is conditional on a boolean variable.

I.e. the paradigm is that there is a fixed superset of known stages, of which individual stages may be conditionally skipped.

**Does Jenkins pipeline script support a model where there is no fixed superset of known stages, and stages can be "looked up" for conditional execution?**

To phrase it as pseudocode, is something along the lines of the following possible:

```
my_list = list populated _somehow_, maybe reading a file, maybe Jenkins build params, etc.

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        if (stage(my_list[0]) exists) {
            run(stage(my_list[0]))
        }
        if (stage(my_list[1]) exists) {
            run(stage(my_list[1]))
        }
        if (stage(my_list[2]) exists) {
            run(stage(my_list[2]))
        }
    }
}
```

?

I think another way to think about what I'm asking is: is there a way to dynamically build a pipeline from some dynamic assembly of stages?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575199/2047614) for an example.

Comment: You would need to do this in Groovy, and therefore it would need to be coded in scripted pipeline, or a shared library's global variable method.

Comment: @MaratC - I wonder if you might be able to expand on your linked answer (either here as an an answer or expanding your linked answer)? I've not seen that "style" of creating a pipeline in my past online research so far, so I don't fully understand the mechanics of how your demonstrated code example works, and would like to learn. Also related come up, like: your linked example seems to run all stages in parallel; can the example be extended to show if stages can be run in serial as well?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic stages you could write either a fully scripted pipeline or use a declarative pipeline with a scripted section (e. g. by using the `script {…}` step or calling your own function). For an overview see [Declarative versus Scripted Pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-versus-scripted-pipeline-syntax) and [Pipeline syntax overview](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#pipeline-syntax-overview).

Declarative pipeline is better supported by Blue Ocean so I personally would use that as a starting point. Disadvantage might be that you need to have a fixed root stage, but I usually name that "start" or "init" so it doesn't look too awkward.

In scripted sections you can call `stage` as a *function*, so it can be used completely dynamic.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('start') {
            steps {
                createDynamicStages()
            }
        }
    }
}

void createDynamicStages() {
    // Stage list could be read from a file or whatever
    def stageList = ['foo', 'bar']
    
    for( stageName in stageList ) {
        stage( stageName ) {
            echo "Hello from stage $stageName"
        }
    }
}
```

This shows in Blue Ocean like this:

[image: Blue Ocean - dynamic stages]

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to ask a bit more to understand further: it looks like you have dynamic stages, each of which has the same "body", which is the `echo` statement. I'd like to understand next: is there a way for each of your dynamic stages to be a distinct function? (e.g. a Groovy script function defined in the `vars/` directory of a Jenkins shared lib)

Comment: @StoneThrow Sure, that would be possible. It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Possibly make that a follow-up question?