# Running dynamic parallel stages in Jenkins with different agents

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am looking to run Jenkins stages in parallel dynamically. Each stage in the parallel stages is run on different agents (jenkins-agent-01, jenkins-agent-02,jenkins-agent-03,jenkins-agent-04).

How to trigger stages dynamically with different agents?

Below is the Jenkinsfile which contains both stages which need to be run dynamically and also sequentially.

Most of the code inside the jenkins stages is same except for agent name and function name and I would like to employ DRY.

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-lib')_

pipeline {
  agent none


  stages {
    stage('initialize') {


      agent {
        label 'jenkins-agent-01'
      }
        steps {
            script {
              //code for loading env and scripts
            }
        }
    }

    stage('UnitTests') {

        parallel {
            stage('UnitTest-Stage1') {
              agent {
                label 'jenkins-agent-02'
              }

              steps {
                script {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                try {
                unitTest.function1()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
               }
              }
            }
            }
           }
           }

          stage('UnitTest-Stage2') {
            agent {
              label 'jenkins-agent-03'
            }
            steps {
              script {
                try {
                unitTest.function3()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
              }
            }        
     }

        stage('UnitTest-Stage3') {
            agent {
              label 'jenkins-agent-04'
            }
            steps {
              script {
                try {
                unitTest.function4()
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
              }
            }       
        }
        }
    }

 stage('Analysis') {

      parallel {
        stage('Analysis-Stage1') {

          steps {
            script {
              try {
                sq.function1()
              }

          catch (Exception e) {
                caughtException = e
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
          }
            }
          }       
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575199/2047614

Comment: Thankyou . The above link shows running on same agent. What If I need to run different stages on different agents in parallel.